# Not displaying products in a JTable Issue

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

Why is my shopping cart not updating and displaying the values when the add to shopping cart button is clicked?

I find it difficult to display the products user selects from the JTable in ShoppingCentre class in the Jtable in the ShoppingCart class

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class WestminsterShoppingCentre extends JFrame {

    private JButton CartBtn;
    private JButton ShoppingCartBtn;
    private JTable prodInfoTable;
    private static ShoppingCart shopcart;
    public static HashMap<String,Product> product_data = new HashMap<>();

    public WestminsterShoppingCentre(String title) throws HeadlessException {
        super(title);
        frameInit();
        WestminsterShoppingManager.ReadInfo(product_data);
        String[] columnNames = {"Product ID","Name","Category","Price(£)","Info"};
        String [] [] data = new String [(product_data.size())] [5];

        int i = 0;
        for(Map.Entry<String, Product> entry : product_data.entrySet()){
            Product product = entry.getValue();
            data [i] [0] = product.getProductID();
            data [i] [1] = product.getProductName();
            data [i] [2] = product.getCategory();
            data [i] [3] = Double.toString(product.getPrice());
            data [i] [4] = product.getInfo();
            i++;

        }

        JPanel SelectPanel = new JPanel();
        SelectPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        // constructing the label with text "Select Product Category"
        JLabel jlblName = new JLabel("Select Product Category : ");
        SelectPanel.add(jlblName);


        // constructing the combo box with choices All,Electronics,Clothing
        JComboBox jcboProductCategory = new JComboBox (new String[]{"All","Electronics","Clothing"});
        SelectPanel.add(jcboProductCategory);

        // constructing shopping cart btn
        CartBtn = new JButton("Shopping Cart");
        SelectPanel.add(CartBtn);

        JPanel TablePanel = new JPanel();
        TablePanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        // constructing the product info table
        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data,columnNames);
        prodInfoTable = new JTable(model);
        TablePanel.add(prodInfoTable);

        // container for a table
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(prodInfoTable);
        TablePanel.add(scrollPane,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        prodInfoTable.setGridColor(Color.BLACK);

        // panel for the product details
        JPanel infopanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(0,25));
        JLabel SelectedProdLbl = new JLabel("Selected Product - Details");
        ShoppingCartBtn = new JButton("Add to Shopping Cart ");
        JLabel text = new JLabel("NBGJDLBLDGB");
        infopanel.add(SelectedProdLbl,BorderLayout.NORTH);
        infopanel.add(text,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        infopanel.add(ShoppingCartBtn,BorderLayout.SOUTH);



        EventHandler handler = new EventHandler();
        CartBtn.addActionListener(handler);
        ShoppingCartBtn.addActionListener(handler);

        // visualise the table and the frame
        setLayout(new BorderLayout ());
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        add(TablePanel);
        add(SelectPanel,BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(scrollPane,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(infopanel,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        setSize(700,600);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private class EventHandler implements ActionListener{
        private int quantity = 0;
        private String [] [] data = new String [0][3];
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

            if(event.getSource() == CartBtn){
                ShoppingCart sc = new ShoppingCart("Shopping Cart");
            } else if (event.getSource() == ShoppingCartBtn ) {
                int SelectedRow = prodInfoTable.getSelectedRow();
                if(SelectedRow != -1){
                    String productID = (String) prodInfoTable.getValueAt(SelectedRow,0);  // https://docs.oracle.com/javase%2F7%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2F%2F/javax/swing/JTable.html#getValueAt(int,%20int)
                    String productName = (String) prodInfoTable.getValueAt(SelectedRow,1);
                    String  productdetails= (String) prodInfoTable.getValueAt(SelectedRow,4);

                    String priceString= (String) prodInfoTable.getValueAt(SelectedRow, 3);
                    double price = Double.parseDouble(priceString);
                    boolean productExisting = false;
                    for(int i = 0; i < shopcart.cartTable.getRowCount();i++){
                        if(productID.equals(shopcart.cartTable.getValueAt(i,0))){
                            int quantity = (Integer) shopcart.cartTable.getValueAt(i, 1) + 1;
                            ShoppingCart.cartTable.setValueAt(quantity, i, 1); // Update quantity
                            productExisting = true;
                            break;
                        }
                        if (!productExisting) {
                            shopcart.addProductToCart(productID, 1, price);
                            shopcart.setVisible(true);
                        }

                    }

//                    String Product = s + "\n" + y + "\n" + z ;
//                    quantity++;
//
//                    String p = (String)prodInfoTable.getValueAt(SelectedRow,3);
//                    double price = Double.parseDouble(p) * quantity;
//                    String [] [] newData = new String[data.length + 1][3];
//                    System.arraycopy(data,0,newData,0,data.length);
//                    newData [data.length][0] = Product;
//                    newData [data.length][1] = Integer.toString(quantity);
//                    newData [data.length][2] = Double.toString(price);
//                    ShoppingCart.loadProductInfoToCart(newData);
                }
            }
        }
    }




}

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ShoppingCart extends JFrame {
    private ArrayList<String> listOfProducts = new ArrayList<>();
    private double total_cost;

    public static JTable cartTable;
    private String [][] data = new String[1][3];

    private String[] columnNames = {"Product","Quantity","Price ($)"};

    public ShoppingCart(String title){
        super(title);
        setVisible(true);
        setSize(700,600);

        JPanel cartTablePanel  = new JPanel();
        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data,columnNames);
        cartTable = new JTable(model);
        cartTablePanel.add(cartTable);

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(cartTable);
        cartTablePanel.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        cartTable.setGridColor(Color.BLACK);

        add(cartTablePanel);
        add(scrollPane,BorderLayout.CENTER);


    }
    public static void addProductToCart(String productName, int quantity, double price) {
        DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) cartTable.getModel();
        model.addRow(new Object[]{productName, quantity, price});
    }

//    public static void loadProductInfoToCart(String [] [] array){
//        data = array;
//        //data = new String[][]{new String[]{Product}, new String[]{Integer.toString(quantity)}, new String[]{Double.toString(price)}};
//    }
}
```

I tried using several methods and then static variables from shopping cart class in the shopping manager class but it's not displaying any values in the Jtable in Shopping Cart class

Comment: I see an empty `Map` and an empty array... In any case, you should separate the gui from your `TableModel`. Load the data in a separate method. I don't know what *WestminsterShoppingManager.ReadInfo(product_data);* does as you haven't posted it. It has nothing to do with your array or `Map` currently. btw method names [begin lower case](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/106-java-style-conventions)

Comment: The first thing I would do would be to create a custom `TableModel` which wrapped the `Product` class - this will make it SO much easier to interact with over time

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of issue which aren't helping you.  Your "core" issue with regards to your question can be found in your `EventHandler` class...

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    if (event.getSource() == CartBtn) {
        ShoppingCart sc = new ShoppingCart("Shopping Cart");
    } 
    //...
```

You're creating a new instance of `ShoppingCart` and assigning it to a local variable, which, once the method exists, is lost.  This means that the `static` property of your outer class is never assigned a value and when you do...

```
if (!productExisting) {
    shopcart.addProductToCart(productID, 1, price);
    shopcart.setVisible(true);
}
```

you end up with a `NullPointerException`.

The simple answer is to assign the new instance of the `ShoppingCart` to the `shopcart` property (maybe check that the value is `null` first).

However, my gut feeling is, you should be making use of [dependency injection](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+dependency+injection), so that things like the product information and shopping cart are passed into the class.

You should also avoid `static` in this context, it's not your friend and isn't going to help you in the long run.

I would also consider creating a custom `TableModel` which could wrap (a `List` of) `Product`.  This will make you life so much easier in the long run.

I'd also discourage you from extending from top level containers like `JFrame` and instead, base you UI's on `JPanel` instead and then add them to what ever container you want to use.  This creates a more flexible and reusable solution.